# Verify the columns (name and amount) returned by a SQL query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've a thirdy-part plugin of my program that execute SQL queries (mostly are select). These queries must return a default column order and amount, such:

```
PACKAGEID (guid), REFDATE (datetime), MODIFYDATE (datetime), PROG (int)
```

Sometimes happens that some query omit one of the column specified above. In order to avoid furthers errors in the program, I would execute a sort of check just to be sure that each query executed returns the default columns.
I've already use the SQL syntax `SET NOEXEC ON` and `SET NOEXEC OFF` and might be useful also in this case. I'm currently using SQL SERVER 2008.
Any hints?

Comment: Will the columns always have the same names?  Do you want to do your query sanity check on the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to put the result set into a temporary table, you can easily count number of columns of the table by using something like:

```
Select * 
From tempdb.Information_Schema.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME like '%#temptable%'
```